# Unable to run python script with PHP exec when importing cv2

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to run a python script which imports cv2 using the PHP exec command. Here is the code:

```
<?php
 $r =  exec('python /home/me/helloWorld.py');
 echo "Output: $r"
 ?>
```

I have two python scripts, helloWorld.py and helloOpencv.py

helloWorld.py

```
print "Hello World"
```

helloOpencv.py

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

helloWorld.py gives the expected output but helloOpencv.py returns "blank"

Somethings I already tried:

- Changed all permission to '777' to check.
- Checked 'which python', 'whoami'
- cv2.so file in current directory
- Changed max exec time (though it doesnt matter for the helloOpencv.py)

I changed the PHP script to report the return_val as follows:

```
<?php
 $r =  exec('python /home/me/helloWorld.py', $ouput, $ret_val);
 echo "ret_val: $ret_val"
 ?>
```

This returned '1' even though there should not be any error in running the helloOpencv.py python script

Please help me find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same problem.